# Why am I getting an overflowerror in Python?

Tags: python, random, encoding, base64

here's my code

```
J = random.randrange(400000000000000000, 800000000000000000)
K = codecs.encode(J.to_bytes(2, 'big'), "base64")
```

but i'm getting an overflow error when trying to run this...
Basically I'm generating a number between 400000000000000000 and 800000000000000000 and converting it to base64. If anyone could help, that'd be great, thanks

Comment: Pleas provide an executable minimal example.

Comment: The `encode` call does not refer to `J` at all.  And what is `ID`?

Comment: sorry, meant J not ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the problem is an overflow :

```
import random, codecs
J = random.randrange(400000000000000000, 800000000000000000)
K = codecs.encode(J.to_bytes(2, 'big'), "base64")
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

The problem is that you don't give him enough bytes in `J.to_bytes(2, 'big')`. If you check the table below, you'll see that to represent numbers as big, you need 8 bytes to store them.

To fix the problem, you need to replace `2` bytes by `8` in the `to_bytes` function:

```py
J.to_bytes(8, 'big')
```

Here is an array of possibilities per size in byte (2^bits).

| Bytes | Possibilities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `256` |
| 2 | `65 536` |
| 4 | `4 294 967 296` |
| 7 | `72 057 594 037 927 900` |
| 8 | `18 446 744 073 709 600 000` |
| Wanted: | `800 000 000 000 000 000` |

Please note that if the byte representation is signed, the maximum number is divided by 2, as 1 bit is used for the sign (+/-). So if the number you want to store is `200` as a `signed int`, then 2 bytes will be needed (-128 to +127) instead of one byte if it's an `unsigned int` (0 to 255).